# Add tensorflow embedding layer to dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding, transformer-model

I'm building a tensorflow model that's a bit of a light transformer.

The input data is of shape (None, 49, 16). Sort of like a language model where every sentence in the data has 49 words, and each word is represented by a vector of size 16.

I will pass each of those 49 vectors of size 16 through a dense layer that has 32 neurons.  The output of this is (None, 49, 32).

To each of these 49 vectors I want to add a vector of size 32, so that I have 49 vectors of size 32, where each entry of these needs to be learned. This is 49*32 = 1568 numbers that need to be learned.

I can build such a model with

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(49,16))
inp2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(49))
mid = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(inp)
emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=49, output_dim=32)(inp2)
out = mid+emb
mod = tf.keras.models.Model([inp,inp2],out)
```

But the inp2 layer must ALWAYS take the same input - [0,1,2,..,48] - for this to work.

Is there a way to simplify this so I don't need 2 separate input layers?

I thought I could do:

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(49,16))
mid = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(inp)
pos = tf.range(start=0, limit=49, delta=1)
emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=49, output_dim=32)(pos)
out = mid+emb
mod = tf.keras.models.Model(inp,out)
```

But when I do this, the 1568 numbers in the embedding are initialized at random and then never learned, which is not what I want.